# Data Not Binding in Asp.Net Data Grid using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, binding, grid

I have created a web method (vb.net) which returns a data set. When I bind the data in grid thru JQuery, it doesn't show the records in grid. The grid is an Infragistics control. I have pasted the code below and need your help to fix it.

**Code:**

```
'<'System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _<br/>
'<'ScriptMethodAttribute(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _<br/>
Public Shared Function BindDataT() As [String]<br/>

    Dim ds As New DataSet("MyDSET")
    Dim dt As New DataTable("MYDTABLE")

    dt.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Dosage", GetType(Integer))

    dt.Rows.Add("David", "Indocin", 10)
    dt.Rows.Add("John", "Enebrel", 30)
    dt.Rows.Add("Lee", "Hydrala", 20)
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

   Return ds.GetXml()
End Function


'<'script type="text/javascript"><br/>
$(function () {<br/>
$('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {<br/>
<br/>
$.ajax({<br/>
        type: "POST",<br/>
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",<br/>
        dataType: "json",<br/>
        url: "DrugDescp.aspx/BindDataT",<br/><br/>
            success: function OnSuccess(response) {<br/>
 // alert message shows all 3 records <br/>
        alert(response.d)<br/><br/>
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);<br/>
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);<br/>
                var getInstvDS = xml.find("MYDTABLE");
      <br/><br/>                 
             var row = $("[id*=grdKK] tr:last-child").clone(true);                    <br/>
            $("[id*=grdKK] tr").not($("[id*=grdKK] tr:first-child")).remove();<br/><br/>
            $.each(getInstvDS, function () {<br/>
            var bookData = $(this);<br/>
            alert($(this).find(0).text());<br/>
            $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Patient").text());<br/>
            $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("Drug").text());<br/>
            $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Dosage").text());<br/>
            $("[id*=grdKK]").append(row);<br/>
            row = $("[id*=grdKK] tr:last-child").clone(true);<br/>
             });<br/>    
            };,<br/>
        });<br/>
     });<br/>
   });<br/>
</script>
<br/>
<br/>//Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.UltraWebGrid<br/>
'<'igtbl:ultrawebgrid id="grdKK" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using jquery datatable. That might solve your problem.